# RavenDB Transformation - Exception thrown on transforming Id

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am trying to run a RavenDB transform, but I'm running into the following exception:

> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not read value for property: Id ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I assume this is because my models use integer Ids rather than strings. How can I get the transform to work with ints?

**DiscountCode_ViewModel.cs**

```
public class DiscountCode_ViewModel : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<DiscountCode>
{
    public DiscountCode_ViewModel()
    {
        TransformResults = discounts => discounts
            .Select(discount => new SimpleDiscountCode
            {
                // Throws an exception here
                Id = discount.Id,
                MerchantId = discount.MerchantId,
                TermsAndConditions = discount.TermsAndConditions,
                Code = discount.Code,
                Description = discount.Description
            });
    }
}
```

**DiscountCode.cs**

```
public class DiscountCode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string TermsAndConditions { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    // a bunch more properties...
}
```

**SimpleDiscountCode.cs**

```
public class SimpleDiscountCode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
}
```

**DiscountCode_ByMerchantId.cs**

```
public class DiscountCodes_ByMerchantId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DiscountCode>
{
    public DiscountCodes_ByMerchantId()
    {
        Map = discounts => discounts
            .Select(discount => new
            {
                discount.MerchantId,
                discount.StartDate,
                discount.EndDate,
                discount.SortOrder
            });

        Sort(x => x.SortOrder, SortOptions.Int);
    }
}
```

**Query.cs**

```
var discounts = await session
                .Query<DiscountCode, DiscountCodes_ByMerchantId>()
                .Include<DiscountCode, Merchant>(d => d.MerchantId)
                .Where(x => x.MerchantId == id)
                .Where(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && x.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
                .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
                .TransformWith<DiscountCode_ViewModel, SimpleDiscountCode>()
                .ToListAsync();

var merchant = await session.LoadAsync<Merchant>(id);
```

Stack Trace

> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Could not read value for property: Id
>     Source=Raven.Abstractions
>     StackTrace:
>          at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 2015
>          at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 434
>          at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 180
>          at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 732
>          at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.DeserializedResult[T](RavenJObject result) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 262
>          at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 190
>          at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.b__26_0[T](RavenJObject x) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 139
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.ToList()
>          at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete[T]() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 138
>          at Raven.Client.Document.AsyncDocumentQuery`1.d__118.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AsyncDocumentQuery.cs:line 1230
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Raven.Client.Document.AsyncDocumentQuery`1.<ToListAsync>d__110.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AsyncDocumentQuery.cs:line 1157
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>          at TCB.MerchantService.Data.MerchantRepository.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\GitCode\TCB.MerchantService\src\TCB.MerchantService.Data\MerchantRepository.cs:line 64
>     InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146233033
>          Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
>          Source=System.Private.CoreLib
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>               at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>               at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
>               at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
>               at Raven.Abstractions.Json.JsonNumericConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Abstractions\Json\JsonNumericConverter.cs:line 36
>               at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1769
>               at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 900
>               at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 2005
>          InnerException:

Fiddler Request

> POST /queries HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:8080
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 16
>   Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Origin: http://localhost:8080
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Referer: http://localhost:8080/studio/index.html
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1952671077.1488191167

Comment: You need to post full details about the error (full stack).
If this happens on the client, post the fiddler trace of the request to the ravendb server

Comment: @AyendeRahien I've added the stack trace

Comment: The fiddler request should contain the request & the response that the server gave you